# Pyspark SQL Select but with a function?

Tags: sql, pyspark

I am looking at this SQL query:

```
SELECT 
  tbl.id as id,
  tbl. as my_name,
  tbl.account as new_account_id,
  CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC', 'America/Los_Angeles', tbl.entry_time)::DATE AS my_time
FROM tbl
```

I am wondering how I would convert this into a Pyspark dataframe?

Say I loaded `tbl` as a CSV into Pyspark like:

```
tbl_dataframe = spark...load('/files/tbl.csv')
```

Now I want to use `SELECT` on this dataframe, something like:

```
final_dataframe = tbl_dataframe.select('id', 'name', ...)
```

The issue here is:

1. How do I rename say that 'name' into 'my_name' with this select?
2. Is it even possible to apply that `CONVERT_TIMEZONE` function with select in dataframe? Whats the best/standard approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How do I rename say that 'name' into 'my_name' with this select?

Assuming your dataframe looks like this

```py
# +---+----+
# | id|name|
# +---+----+
# |  1| foo|
# |  2| bar|
# +---+----+
```

There are few different ways to do this "rename":

```py
df.select(F.col('name').alias('my_name')) # you select specific column and give it an alias
# +-------+
# |my_name|
# +-------+
# |    foo|
# |    bar|
# +-------+

# or
df.withColumn('my_name', F.col('name')) # you create new column with value from old column
# +---+----+-------+
# | id|name|my_name|
# +---+----+-------+
# |  1| foo|    foo|
# |  2| bar|    bar|
# +---+----+-------+

# or
df.withColumnRenamed('name', 'my_name') # you rename column
# +---+-------+
# | id|my_name|
# +---+-------+
# |  1|    foo|
# |  2|    bar|
# +---+-------+
```

> 2. Is it even possible to apply that `CONVERT_TIMEZONE` function with select in dataframe? What's the best/standard approach for this?

`CONVERT_TIMEZONE` is not a standard Spark function, but if it's a Hive function that is already registered somewhere, you can try this `F.expr('convert_timezone()')`